# Can I convert a 36 volt battery to a 48 volt battery or how do I extend a 48 volt 10 amp hours to 48 volt 20 amp hours?

Tags: power-supply, amperage, conversion

How do I convert a 48 volt 10 amp hours to 48 volt 20 amp hours battery? Can I convert a 36 volt battery to a 48 volt battery?

Comment: While the question title and the question body are at odds, I suggest 1) Obtain a 48 V 20 Ah battery. 2) Sell the old battery.

Comment: Andrew has the right idea. If there's some reason you have to use this battery you can shore it up with more batteries and you can use a circuit called a boost converter to increase voltage. But it's way easier if you just buy the right battery you need.

Comment: Is this a battery pack or a single battery?

Comment: Yes, we'd need to know more about the batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to convert a 48 V 10 AH battery to a 48 V 20 AH battery is to connect 2 in parallel.

You can use a boost converter to increase the voltage of a 36 V battery to 48 V.

The Amp-Hour capability will be whatever the 36 V battery is, but keep in mind the current draw will be higher from the 36 V battery to compensate.  Assuming a decent converter (best case): Your amp hours at 48 V will be whatever the 36 V battery's is multiplied by the voltage ratio. (It will be 3/4 to AH of the 36 V battery)

$$1\ AH\ @\ 36\ V = 36/48\ AH\ @\ 48\ V = 0.75\ AH\ @\ 48\ V$$

Comment: Thank y'all who took the time to help me with my dilemma. The batteries are battery packs for an ebike. I managed to find the corresponding video tutorial on you tube. All I need to do is increase the amount of batteries in parallel to increase the amp hours and increase the batteries in sync to increase the voltage. I can use the same battery management system on my 48 volt battery but will need to get the appropriate one for the 36 volt batteries to convert them to 48 volt batteries.  A simple fix. I thought this was the answer but was hit with 10,000 once and have been wary ever since.